# How to close pop up in Selenium web driver?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium2

Please help me out for this problem.

**I tried to close this Pop-up page with Selenium, but not able to do it.**

**HTML code**

```
<div class="popupsignup-disp">
   <div class="popupsignup-cntbox">
      <div class="container-fluid">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 ntp-cnt-wrap">
               <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-12 text-center voffset4"><img alt="" src="/static/img/nico-tides-moon.png"></div>
                  <div class="col-xs-12 voffset3 hidden-xs hidden-sm"></div>
                  <div class="col-xs-12 voffset2">
                     <h3 class="npr">This full moon’s extra special, and we’ve got prices to match.</h3>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-12 voffset6">
                     <h5 class="text-uppercase head-text">Special Pricing goes live</h5>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-12 voffset3">
                     <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-6 text-right potd-wrap">
                           <div class="pop-time"><span>Online</span> <span class="hlgt">14 + 15 December</span> <span class="small">All Day</span></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6 text-left">
                           <div class="pop-time"><span>In-store</span> <span class="hlgt">14 - 18 December</span> <span class="small">11 am To 8 pm</span></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="pop-divider"></div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-12 voffset5"><a class="text-uppercase pop-btn" href="/catalogue/category/special-price/women_126/" id="ntnc-linknclose">Shop now</a></div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <a class="close-popupsignup-wrap"></a>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Add your code here, what you have tried for closing pop up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Driver.SwitchTo().frame("Fancybox-frame");

Driver.findElement("enter your xpath to close popup").click();

Driver.SwitchTo().defaultContent();
```

Comment: It is not working.

Answer (score 3):

You may try taking `XPath` of that close button which is on pop up:

```
WebElement closebtn = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@class,'close-popupsignup-wrap')]"));
closebtn.click();
```

or using this `XPath` expression:

```
//a[@class='close-popupsignup-wrap']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. get the window handle, (provide proper delay)
2. switch to that pop up, then click on Cross icon using XPath
3. after that switch to default, it might work

Answer (score 0):

**You have below options to close pop-up:**

- Click on "X" [close] icon on pop-up to close
- You can click on any other visible element on page other than pop-up

**How:**

- You can simply use id, name or css & perform click

Answer (score 0):

There is another better way which im using some times.
User key board keys
Eg: `Tab` key to navigate to the popup box.
Again `Tab` key to navigate to the button.
Hit `Enter` key or Space key to get rid of popup.